# SQLAlchemy subquery comparison

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following set of tables:

```
class Job(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'jobs'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


class Informant(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'informants'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    job_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('jobs.id'))
    max_students = db.Column(db.Integer)        


class Student(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'students'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


queues = db.Table('queues',
                  db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('students.id')),
                  db.Column('job_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('jobs.id')),
                  PrimaryKeyConstraint('student_id', 'job_id'))
```

Now I need to obtain something like:

```
SELECT jobs.id
FROM jobs
WHERE (
    SELECT SUM(informants.max_students)
    FROM informants
    WHERE informants.job_id = jobs.id
) <= (
    SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM queues
    WHERE queues.job_id = jobs.id
)
```

So basically I search the jobs with an amount of students that exceed the maximal capacity, the sum of the related informants' capacities. Is there a clean way to do this in `SQLAlchemy`? I tried the following:

```
db.session.query(Job.id).filter( \
    db.session.query(db.func.sum(Informant.max_students)). \
        filter(Informant.job_id == Job.id) <= \
    db.session.query(db.func.count(1)).select_from(queues). \
        filter(queues.c.job_id == Job.id))
```

This yields something like `SELECT jobs.id FROM jobs WHERE 0 = 1`. Is there something I'm missing, because I have successfully used similar queries before. Or am I better of using `db.engine.execute` to execute the raw SQL?

Comment: Why don't you move 'max_students' to Job? The query will be much easier after that.

Comment: Because an informant chooses the maximal amount of students he wants to serve. Students should be placed on a queue (for new informants with the same job) if no more informants with the full informant's job are available. I know the query is rather complex, maybe I'll just set a flag if a job is open for queuing. Students choose informants in the first place, and they need to know whether an informant is full. If that is the case, they are placed in a queue for the informant's job.

Comment: Well, what's next? I think that you can place the column `max_students` into `jobs` table. If `job_id` is not unique in `informants`, well, you can sum them into one row in `jobs` table. You do anyway, but now - by `SUM` into your query. I don't see necessity of being `informants` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was close to having the right answer. The piece that was missing is an `as_scalar` method on both subqueries. So the final query is:

```
db.session.query(Job.id).filter( \
    db.session.query(db.func.sum(Informant.max_students)). \
        filter(Informant.job_id == Job.id).as_scalar() <= \
    db.session.query(db.func.count(1)).select_from(queues). \
        filter(queues.c.job_id == Job.id).as_scalar())
```

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the correct solution.